# Leyenda dinámica en Grafica de Power Bi según año filtrado

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo una grafica simple en Power Bi, que compara el año filtrado con un año anterior. El problema está en que visualmente no logro hacer que en la leyendo muestre ( ) 2023 - ( ) 2022. Que seria 2023 el año filtrado y automaticamente reconozca el 2022 como el año anterior y lo muestre. Al momento de crear medidas muestra: ( ) Ventas Actual - ( ) Ventas año anterior. Pero quiero ver los años, no otro nombre.

Lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, no importa el año filtrado... me muestra en la leyenda el nombre de las medidas y quiero el de los años filtrados.